# How to reuse only some variables in tensor flow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a class in tensorflow which has weights and document embeddings. I will use it for both my training and validation. My query is that is it possible in tensorflow session for validation set to reuse only weights from my training and not the embeddings and let it learn new document embeddings for valid set. Snippet of code.

```
Class NewModel(Object):
  def __init__(self, is_training, vocabuary_size, embedding_size):
    self.X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 300])  
    self.doc_int = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None]) 

    self.embeddings=tf.get_variable("embedding", [vocabulary_size ,embedding_size],initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1))
    self.embedval = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings ,self.doc_int)
    self.weights = tf.get_variable("weights",weight_shapeinitializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
    biases = tf.get_variable("biases", bias_shape,initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    # Some neural network with optimiser and loss that will train weight and embeddings..

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:

  initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer()
  with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
    train = NewModel(is_training=True, vocabulary_size=4000,\
    embedding_size =50)
    with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True,   initializer=initializer):
      valid = NewModel(is_training=False, vocabulary_size= 1000, embedding_size = 50)
 # Here is where I am confused. I want to use trained variable of weight but not embeddings and 
 want new embeddings to be trained for valid set.
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
 # will call some function to run epochs and stuff
```

Maybe using different scope names could help but still would need some advice on proceeding about it. Or is it possible to just mention it somewhere which variables to be reused.

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps reorganize the NewModel class.

```
Class NewModel(Object):
    def __init__(self, vocabuary_size, embedding_size, initializer):
        self.X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 300])  
        self.doc_int = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None]) 
        self.vocabuary_size = vocabuary_size
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.initializer = initializer

    def initialize_embeddings(self):
        with tf.variable_scope("embed",initializer=initializer) as scope:
             self.embeddings=tf.get_variable("embedding", [self.vocabulary_size ,self.embedding_size],initializer=self.initializer)
             self.embedval = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embeddings ,self.doc_int)
             scope.reuse_variable()

    def initialize_weights(self, weight_shape, biase_shape, initializer=initializer):
        with tf.variable_scope("weight", initializer=initializer) as scope:
             self.weights = tf.get_variable("weights",weight_shapeinitializer=self.initializer)
             biases = tf.get_variable("biases", bias_shape,initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
             scope.reuse_variable()

    def train_network(self):
         # Some neural network with optimiser and loss that will train weight and embeddings..

    def validate_network(self):
         # A function for the validation process
```

This way you have separated the embedding initialization with the weights and biases initialization. The usage of this new class would be like...

```
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:

    initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer()
    model = NewModel(vocabulary_size=4000, embedding_size =50, initializer=initializer) # construct a model instance
    model.initialize_weights(weight_shape, biase_shape) # initialize the weights and biases
    model.initialize_embeddings() # initialize embeddings
    model.train_network() # train the network
    # Before start validation process, re-initialize embeddings
    model.initialize_embeddings()
    model.validate_network()
```